Register network connectivity in AndroidManifest.xml
I know it's no longer possible to register broadcast receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml file,
But I've noticed that some apps are accomplishing that somehow I don't really know.
For example: The Word With Friends gaming app, when I swipe off the app activity in my Device Launcher recent apps page, the app normally will be destroyed since it does not run any Foreground service, but later on usually when I turn on my Device data connection, BOOM! The Word With Friends app popup a notification!
How was that possible when the app has been recently destroyed?
Sorry but when I decompile those app to see as it works, I found a suspicious Receiver in their AndroidManifest.xml file like this:
<receiver android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxy$NetworkStateProxy" android:enabled="false" android:exported="false" android:directBootAware="false"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" /> </intent-filter> </receiver>
But still then, I don't know this works or if it is, that is causing the app to be "RECREATING"
Please someone help
